# Python can't decode \x byte

Tags: pandas, encoding

I have a csv file with about 9 million rows. While processing it in Python, I got an error:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\xe9' in position 63: character maps to undefined

Turns out the string is **Beyonc\xe9** . So I guess it's something like é. 
I tried just printing '\xe' in Python and it failed:

```
>>> print('\xe')
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-2: truncated \xXX escape
```

So I can't even replace or strip the backslash by `s.replace('\\x', '')` or `s.strip('\\x')`.

Is there a quick way to fix this over the whole file? I tried to set the encoding while reading the file:

```
pandas.read_csv(inputFile, encoding='utf-8')
```

but it didn't help. Same problem.

Python version:

```
python --version
Python 3.5.2
```

although I installed [3.6.5](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.5/python-3.6.5.exe)

Windows 10

**Update:**

Following [@Matti's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50051949/900394) I changed the encoding in `pandas.read_csv()` to **latin1** and now the string became **Beyonc\xc3\xa9**. And [**\xc3\xa9** is unicode for é](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=128&number=128&names=-&utf8=string-literal).

This is the line that's failing:

```
print(str(title) + ' , ' + str(artist))

title = 'Crazy In Love'
artist = 'Beyonc\xc3\xa9'
```

api is from [lyricsgenius](https://github.com/johnwmillr/LyricsGenius)

Answer (score 2):

The `'\xe9'` in the error message isn't an actual backslash followed by letters, it's just a representation of a single byte in the file. Your file is probably encoded as Latin-1, not UTF-8 as you specify. Specify `'latin1'` as the encoding instead.

Comment: Now it says `UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 37-38: character maps to <undefined>`, without mentioning the problematic string. But I found that the string is now **Beyonc\xc3\xa9**

Comment: Ok I found [here](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=128&number=128&names=-&utf8=string-literal) that **\xc3\xa9** is indeed a unicode for é

Comment: If I'm reading those error messages right, you file is broken as it seems to be using a mixture of multiple encodings. Using the `'latin1'` encoding should enable you to at least read it (there are no invalid byte sequences in Latin-1), assuming whatever library you're using supports standard Python encodings. Some of the characters would be decoded incorrectly though.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean that it fails on `read_csv()`. That works either way (`utf-8` / `latin1`). I added the line that fails. Please take a look at the update

Comment: Put `utf-8` back because that's what your file is in. Could you post the full stack trace for your error so we can see which function is *actually* failing?

Comment: Thanks, I looked at the stack myself and seems like the *acutal* line that was failing is `print(track + ' , ' + artist)`. I just disabled that line and it worked. But the library (`lyricsgenius`) prints the track name while searching (but not the artist), so I'm afraid this will fail again in some weird track names